# Fastest way to pivot in case of unique indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe

```py
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
    A   B   T   U   V
0   a1  b1  t1  0   1
1   a1  b1  t2  2   3
2   a1  b2  t1  4   5
```

I am pivoting this as

```py
In [2]: df.pivot(index=['A', 'B'], columns=['T'])
Out[2]:
        U       V
    T   t1  t2  t1  t2
A   B               
a1  b1  0.0 2.0 1.0 3.0
    b2  4.0 NaN 5.0 NaN
```

Each combination of columns `A`, `B` and `T` in `df` will have just 1 row, i.e.,

```py
In [2]: df.value_counts(subset=['A','B','T']).max()
Out[2]: 1
```

**Is there a faster way, given the uniqueness assumption?** I expect, one that would not do the unique-combination check any further (which I guess `pivot` does).

Comment: What wrong with the `pivot`? And actually you must have unique values, else you would need `pivot_table`.

Comment: You can try something like `df.set_index(list('ABT')).unstack('T')` but I am not sure  it is going to be faster than pivot.

Comment: @mozway Nothing wrong with `pivot`. I want to be sure am using the optimal way, as I will be trying it out on large datasets.

Comment: I can think of something faster, but it requires a stronger assumption than just uniqueness. It also requires no "holes" in the data. i.e. right now there's no value corresponding to "a1  b2  t2", which results in a NaN in the output. If you're interested in this, look into numpy reshape.

Comment: @Nick it would also need to be sorted perfectly ;)

Comment: @It_is_Chris tried out the approach. `pivot` is slightly faster. I was trying to find some way to do `df.set_index(list('AB')).use_column_values_for_col_index('T')` so that I do not involve `T` in two subsequent operations. However, I did not find any such pandas operation.